# DataStructure for implementing something like nested Maps?

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, dictionary, visitor-pattern

I want to have a map that permits a tree-like behaviour. I want to be able to define a Map from string to an object, that can be another map, or a string:

```
    Map<String,(String OR Map)>
```

The only way I think I know how to do it is through the Visitor Pattern. Is there an already made data structure that implements this?

UPDATE:
Here is the context:
I want to parse form submitted through a post request. The form is multilevel and can have an arbitrary number of fields(chosen by the user). What I decided to do is to name the fields in the form with numbers as such:

1. User|name
2. processor|1|speed
3. processor|1!name
4. processor|2|speed
5. disk|1|name
6. disk|2|name

I decided to break it up at | and then create a tree like structure so itwould look something like this:

- User

  - name = whatever the user inputs
- Processor

  - 1

    - speed = whatever the user inputs
    - name = whatever the user inputs
  - 2

    - speed = whatever the user inputs
- Disk

  - 1

    - name = whatever the user inputs
  - 2

    - name = whatever the user inputs

Only the last leaves would contain strings. There is not that many fields so I had a feeling using a Map may be a bit of an overkill, but honestly I really didn't know how to do this with anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduce an object that represents `String` or `Map`.   Presumably you use them in a way that has some shared behaviour?  This could be abstracted to a common base class, and it sounds a little like the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) (tree-like behaviour).  For example:

```
interface StructuredObject {}

class Leaf implements StructuredObject {}

class Composite implements StructuredObject {}

Map<String, StructuredObject> map = ...;
```

As you point out, you can then use the visitor pattern to traverse through the map and avoid type casting.

Comment: My problem with that is how to implement accessing named elements inside collections. My interface has following methods getElem() returns interface at key, getVal() returns String and putElem() inserts interface. How would I handle a call to getElem from the leaf? Just return null? Similarly how would I handle getVal from the composite?

Comment: You could make Leaf behave like a composite with no children? (sort of like null object).  Ditto for getVal (but the other way around).  I'm not sure of the context though, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I added some context to the question.

Comment: I'd give `StructuredObject` a method `String getElement(String... keys)`: a `Leaf` would implement this by returning its single stored string, and a `Composite` would implement this by taking the first string in the array, finding the corresponding child, calling its `getElement` method with the remainder of the array, and returning the result. Both classes would check that the array is the right length: for a `Leaf`, the array must be length 0, and for a `Composite`, it must be length >0. An incorrect length gets an `IllegalArgumentException`. Thus, the client never has to navigate the tree.

Comment: And you probably want to take a `List` rather than an array, really, because you can do `subList` efficiently rather than having to slice and dice arrays all over the place.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. However, how would you implement the fact that I don't really know how many processors are defined. I need a way of looping through all of them. And the number attached doesn't have to be sequential at all. I think I could get a separate method that allows me to get the Composite and another method to loop through it (something that returns an iterator);

Answer (score 0):

Most map implementations have values of a specific type.  If you want multiple value types you can do this by wrapping a map of your choice, e.g. a TreeMap.

Answer (score -1):

Google Collections has a very nice API `MultiMap` for this use case